# Why can't __array_function__ be called from an instance of an np.ndarray?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to write a custom array container following [numpy's guide](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.dispatch.html) and I can't understand why the following code always returns `NotImplemented`.

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1])
shape = (2, 2)
a.__array_function__(func=np.broadcast_to, types=(np.ndarray, type(shape)), args=(a, shape), kwargs={})
Out[5]: NotImplemented
```

Even though the normal method obviously works

```py
np.broadcast_to(a, shape)
Out[6]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 1]])
```

The function `np.broacast_to` is just an example, `np.reshape` has the same issue.

Does anyone know what my mistake is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`types` is only supposed to include types that actually implement `__array_function__`. `type(shape)` doesn't implement `__array_function__`, so it shouldn't be in `types`.

Comment: That was definitely the problem, so how does `__array_function__` know which type corresponds to which argument if the two iterables have different lengths?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.classes.html?highlight=__array_function__#numpy.class.__array_function__). The first few paragraphs before the example hold the answer.